# Cheetah installing error

Tags: installation, gnuradio, cheetah, usrp

I'm trying to install on my machine gnuradio and to do so I have to install another programs, according to this [site](http://code.ettus.com/redmine/ettus/projects/uhd/wiki/GNURadio_Windows). Everything goes well but when I have to install the cheetah dependency it gives me this error:

> c:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install cheetah
>
> Processing cheetah
>
> error: Not a recognized archive type: cheetah"

How can I install the cheetah dependency correctly? I'm working on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when you last attempted this, but it doesn't look like Cheetah uses easy_install - at least not any longer:

http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/docs/users_guide_html_multipage/gettingStarted.install.html